# Starbase Codewright backup file write and remove errors

Tags: backup, package-management

I am using Codewright 7.0 and am consistently getting an error saying:
Cant copy/move file **"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeWright\cwright.ini** to backup file **C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeWright\cwright.bak**
If I change the Global Backup Spec under Customize -> Environment -> Backup I get the error: Cant delete the existing backup file ***C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeWright***
Even thought there is no backup file in that directory.

I am hoping there are still some people out there who deal with this software. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a copy of `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeWright\cwright.ini` and name it `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeWright\cwright.bak` and just eliminate any perrmission issue launch the application as an Administrator.  With it being from 2008 I suspect it has a problem with the new security model introduced in Windows Vista.

Comment: @Ramhound that worked thank you. If it still shows the error when run without escalated privileges' am I right in thinking there is an issue with our Program Files permissions? What could be the reason it will not work without escalated privs?

Comment: What part of that solution worked exactly?  A ton of programs released in 2008 were never updated to the newer security model introduced by Windows Vista and newer. The fact it's attempting to modify a file in a folder that is typically protected by unelevated users indicates the software was never designed to work on Windows 7+.  Based on the fact you have WoW64 suggests you are running Windows 7 or newer.

Comment: Right we are running windows 10. Once I ran the software as an administrator it worked without an error. I did not need to create a copy of the cwright.ini at that point because Codewright creates it on its own. However when I run it as just a unelevated user it did not work because it cannot create that copy of the cwright.ini. However once I did the copy the error changed to Cant delete the existing backup file as an unelevated user.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the following error:
>
> `Cant delete the existing backup file C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeWright`
>
> Even though there is no backup file in that directory.

Codewright 7.0 was released around the time Windows Vista was released.  Windows Vista brought one major security change that Windows XP did not have and that was the User Account Control (UAC).  With this change Windows protects particularly important directories like Program Files.  Windows 8 further increase this security, a great deal of software that used to work in compatibility mode on Windows 7, ceased to work due to the changes introduced by Windows 8+.

In your case since you are running Windows 10, by default an unelevated user, does not have the permissions required to create a backup of the programs configuration file.  Creating files in the Program Files directory was common in earlier versions of Windows, in later versions due to the UAC, these files are created in other locations.

Since you are running Windows 10, the solution to your problem, is to simply run the application with elevated permissions.  This will allow the backup configuration file to be created and then modified when the application closes.

Answer (score 0):

I've used an old 5.1d version of Codewright for many years now.  Every time I migrate the CW32 folder to a new PC, I begin running into the types of issues described here.  I eventually get past them once I modify my shortcut for cw32.exe to compatibility mode using Win XP SP3.   Haha,  I know, it's very old, but I love using the Brief editor keymapping feature.   If you're using CW Ver 7, you will probably be able to invoke a later version of Windows when setting compatibility mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).